# Mutiple Views for a Doc in MFC MDI application

Tags: mfc, multiple-views

I would like to have multiple views for a document in my MDI MFC application. In order to do that, InitInstance of my App class has following code

```
m_pMainTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_OpenCVTestTYPE,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyDoc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CImageView));
if (!m_pMainTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(m_pMainTemplate);

m_pHistTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_OpenCVTestTYPE,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyDoc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CHistogramView));
if (!m_pHistTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(m_pHistTemplate);
```

But when I start the application, it keeps asking which document among two documents user wants to choose. Of course, those documents are the same kind. Any idea or hint to resolve this problem?

**UPDATE:** I resolved the problem by having separate menu for the second view and overriding OnFileNew like this

```
 void CMyApp::OnFileNew()
 {
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    m_pMainTemplate->OpenDocumentFile(NULL);
 }
```

Comment: Overriding OnFileNew is the right approach in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add a second template.

This [Microsoft KB article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s199bks0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) shows how to create multiple views for a single doc.

EDIT: One possibilty is to modify your document template before opening the child frame that must have the alternate view.

```
m_pMainTemplate->m_m_pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(CHistogramView);
```

You should then probably set the view in the template before opening any kind of child frame in order to make sure that the template is in the expected state for every child frame opening.

Comment: If you read the article with some care, you will notice it is for SDI. Mine is for MDI.

Comment: The techniques can be adapted to MDI: Just let the user open a new child frame and replace the view upon frame creation

Comment: I also thought that way but in MDI, why would you switch views? Actual requirement is to show both views too. FYI: I've already tried it but that does not work for MDI.

Comment: You want to show 1 view per child frame, right? So you switch views in the frame that should come up with the alternate view.

Comment: I just resolved my issue with simple change. I updated my answer. Thanks for your effort anyway.